# DNS Configuration for Azure Load Balancer with Public IP

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, load-balancing, traffic, load-balance

I'm configuring a load balancer in Azure to distribute traffic to backend VMs for my web application (most likely just a singular VM actually). I'm a bit confused about the DNS setup. Here's what I have (I will use dummy names):

I've deployed a load balancer named "FlowerLoadBal" in the "UK South" region of Azure.
I want users to access the web application using the subdomain "Flower.mydomain.com".

The load balancer has a public IP address associated with it.
Here's what I'm planning to do in my DNS configuration:

**A Record:**

Host: FlowerLoadBal

Value: Public IP address of the load balancer

**CNAME Record:**

Host: Flower

Target: FlowerLoadBal.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com

Is this the correct approach for configuring DNS to point to the Azure load balancer with a public IP?
I believe this is correct. When they enter Flower.mydomain.com it should point them to the load balancer which will then send them onto the VM (after I configure it).

Are there any potential issues or improvements I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with Azure DNS with just an A record as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#public-ip-address

It really depends on your scenario but some things to consider at a high level:

- Will you need to scale your VM out based on load? Have you considered using a VM Scale Set here
- if you're using Azure Loadbalancer the VM web host will need to deal with the SSL / TLS.
- Do you have to host on a VM , if you can host on Azure App Service or Azure Container Apps then a lot of features you may require are already provided with these Platform as a service offerings which can be cheaper in the long run
- Azure Loadbalancer is Layer3/4 (it's implemented through the software defined networking, so it isnt a "real" appliance). But for a web application then a Layer7 load balancer like Azure Application Gateway, or Azure Front Door can provide many more features relevant to a web app and both optionally support a WAF policy.
- if using the VM ensure that you also use an NSG and that other ports (RDP, SSH etc) are blocked so only web traffic is allowed.

This is not an exhaustive list

Comment: Part 1 - 
Hi, thank you for your response! I have a few answer to your questions

Firstly, 1 WEB VM will definitely be enough. Also, we HAVE to host on a VM unfortunately.
For SSL/TLS, our IIS will deal with this, so that shouldn't be an issue.
We literally just need it for 3 sites all going to just port 80/443, it's not an extensive list hitting the VM/Load balancer. So I think a load balancer will be enough for what we need.

Comment: Part 2 - We also don't use azure DNS, we use an external company.

You say we can do it with just an A record. But then how would the 3 sites resolve to the load balancer? Are you saying I do hostname = Flower, value = IP Address. hostname = Rose, value = IP address. Because I was pretty sure we needed the 2 entries I originally put above, in the DNS server?

Comment: part 2 - if you plan to use a DNS label on the IP (<name>.<region>.cloudapp.azure.com) then you're using Azure DNS even if you CNAME from another provider. Az LB doesnt care about the http hostheader (or anything http) only about tcp flows, so the web server itself will need to filter on the 3 different hostheaders to match the correct site. In the end all 3 site hostheaders/FQDN from a client perspective will need to  resolve via DNS to the *same* Az public IP address value (as all 3 sites are on the same VM). If each site is a subdomain of the primary you could use a wild card A record.

Comment: part 1 - you state in the question that it's a single VM,  have you considered simplifying further and just using a public IP (standard) on the VM? Both Standard LB and Standard VIP require Network security group and are therefore secure by default. The way the DNS works applies equally to both.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! So I am going to use a LB instead of a PIP directly onto the VM as it adds another layer of security, so we don't expose the VM to the public directly. And correct me if I am wrong, but if I point all 3 subdomain sites to the LB PIP, via 3 separate A records, that will work as intended? Then the IIS handles where the hostnames need to go, SSL/TLS etc. Correct? Thanks again!

Comment: It is the NSG that provides the security Michael :) not the LB. In fact both the NSG and LB (along with UDR) are a product of the SDN not "real" appliances. The standard IP on a LB or the Standard IP on the VM are therefore equal. Where the LB is advantageous is if you have more than one backend VM target and/or you want outbound NAT. A records should work fine here equally as long as the FQDN for each site it unique you should be able to CNAME each to the same target (cloudapp.azure.com host label). You cant CNAME for an apex domain and a CNAME record cant have the same name as another record